# How to get output from paging container into a variable | Getting single virtual network from resource group

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-network

Thanks in advance, I have variable at the top of my code, LOCATION, VNET_NAME, SUBNET, SUBNETRANGE. I want to fill this information from the output of function List_VNET. Using this function I'm getting virtual network from resource group on azure (I've only single virtual network per resource group). And then wanted to populate it into the variable but it is giving output as paging container. I mostly work on powershell hence i know about arrays and we can get an instance using array[0].

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute.models import DiskCreateOption
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import NetworkSecurityGroup
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import SecurityRule
import azure.mgmt.network.models


SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 'xxx'
GROUP_NAME = 'AQRG'
LOCATION = ''
VM_NAME = 'myVM'
VNET_NAME = ''
SUBNET_NAME = ''
SUBNETRANGE = ''


def List_VNET(network_client):
    result_create = network_client.virtual_networks.list(
            GROUP_NAME,
        )
    SUBNET_NAME = result_create


    return SUBNET_NAME

def get_credentials():
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = 'xxxx',
        secret = 'xxxx',
        tenant = 'xxxx'
    )

    return credentials


if __name__ == "__main__":
    credentials = get_credentials()

resource_group_client = ResourceManagementClient(
    credentials, 
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID
)
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
    credentials, 
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID
)

creation_result = List_VNET(network_client)
print("------------------------------------------------------")
print(creation_result)
input('Press enter to continue...')
```

Getting output as below

```
<azure.mgmt.network.v2018_12_01.models.virtual_network_paged.VirtualNetworkPaged object at 0x0000023776C13908>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Define the VNET_NAME as global in the function `List_VNET`:

```
   SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 'xxx'
   GROUP_NAME = 'AQRG'
   LOCATION = ''
   VM_NAME = 'myVM'
   VNET_NAME = ''
   SUBNET_NAME = ''
   SUBNETRANGE = ''


def List_VNET(network_client):
    result_create = network_client.virtual_networks.list(
            GROUP_NAME
        )
    global VNET_NAME
    for re in result_create:
        VNET_NAME=re.name

    return VNET_NAME
```

---

After the code: `creation_result = List_VNET(network_client)`

add the following code:

```
for re in creation_result:
    print(re.name)
```

Then you can get all the virtual networks' name.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you for replying. I've one question. when i do this 
{
    for re in result_create:
        VNET_NAME = re.name
    return VNET_NAME
}
it doesn't save the value in the variable. At the top I've specified the variable as blank and wanted the output of the function to fill in the variable.

Comment: I have only one in my resource group. And it will always be single VNET per RG

Comment: You should define the  VNET_NAME as global. I have updated my answer. If it works, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I'm new to Python and still learning. One last querie I've to get the region of the virtual network but unable to get it as the output only gives re.name but no re.region

Do you know if this can be achieved through a different function


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2019_02_01.operations.virtual_networks_operations.virtualnetworksoperations?view=azure-python#list-resource-group-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-

Comment: @aquib.qureshi, do you mind submitting a new question about that? Thanks you :). And please let me know the question's url.

Comment: i thought you might feel awkward because of a simple question hence did not raise it. Kindly find the below link


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035949/getting-all-the-properties-of-a-vnet-using-python-list-function-only-gives-nam

Comment: @aquib.qureshi, it takes some time to figure out the properties of virtual network, and just use print(re) , I can get all the properties of virtual network.